# Converting Dictionary to List in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

How do I save the list of items if `'boa'` is in `href` to a list? I don't want to print them using get() but instead convert them to a list in their own variable (it seems these are in a dictionary?), preferably to `boat_links`. Thanks!

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Open Craigslist with BeautifulSoup and save to file

url = 'http://losangeles.craigslist.org/boo/'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
webContent = response.read()

f = open('C:\Users\dell\Desktop\python\\boat_crawler\craigslist.html', 'w')
f.write(webContent)
f.close

html_doc = open('C:\Users\dell\Desktop\python\\boat_crawler\craigslist.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

boat_links = []

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    if 'boa' in a['href']:
    print a.get('href')
```

Comment: `boat_links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a') if 'boa' in a['href']]`

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to do this in a `for` loop on it's own?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want a list or dictionary or a dictionary of lists so here are all of them

```
if a.get('href').find('boa')>-1:
    boat_links.append(a.get('href'))
```

Here is a dictionary with the a tags text as the key and the href as the value

```
boat_links = {}
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    if a.get('href').find('boa')>-1:
         boat_links[a.text] = a.get('href')
```

Here is a dictionary of lists based on the a.tags (what if you have multiple links with the same text)

```
boat_links = {}
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    if a.get('href').find('boa')>-1
         if boat_links.has_key(a.text):
              boat_links[a.text].append(a.get('href'))
         else:
              boat_links[a.text] = [a.get('href')]
```